# How to start item index with 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, foreach

I'm iterating through array "fruits". I want its index to start with 1. but the output starts at 0.
Here is my code

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

here is the output.

```
0:apple
1:orange
2:cherry
```

how do i make it to start with 1 ?

Comment: try `var fruits = [null,"apple", "orange", "cherry"];`

Comment: forEach starts index from the 0. you need to manually increase the index value in the innerHTML. (index+1) + ":" + ...

Comment: _"how do i make it to start with 0 ?"_ - it already does?

Comment: so add one?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually add 1 to the index:

```
(index + 1)
```

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (index + 1) + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(item, index) {
    var index2 = index + 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index2 + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    myFunction(fruits[i], i);
}

function myFunction(item, index) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the foreach method on a new array starting from the element you want. You can do that by using the slice method.

```
fruits.slice(1).forEach(myFunction);
```

You can check this link to get more informations about the slice method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp.